# Update Remoting Credentials Without Reload

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting, session

I've got a native iOS app that uses a WKWebView to display a Visualforce page. This page makes extensive use of remoting, and currently I'm trying to determine a strategy to deal with session timeouts: I want to be able to refresh the session *without* having to reload the page.

The Salesforce docs detail this process for hybrid apps:

```
// Refresh oauth token
cordova.require("com.salesforce.plugin.oauth").authenticate(
    function(creds) {
        // Reload hidden iframe that points to a blank page to
        // to refresh Visualforce domain cookies
        var iframe = document.getElementById("blankIframeId");
        iframe.src = src;

        // Refresh CSRF cookie
        // Get the provider array
        var providers = Visualforce.remoting.Manager.providers;
        // Get the last provider in the arrays (usually only one)
        var provider = Visualforce.remoting.last;
        provider.refresh(function() {
            //Retry call for a seamless user experience
        });

    }, 
    function(error) {
        console.log("Refresh failed");
    }
);
```

So far I've got the refresh token being used to reauthenticate the session in the native code being triggered by Javscript, and I've got the resulting data structure coming back to a Javascript function—it's identical to that provided by the cordova plugin to the `creds` parameter in the snippet above.

**What I want to know is how I go about using and applying this new session information**. Presumably the cordova plugin does something sneaky and writes taht info somewhere, because the `creds` argument is not being used in the code above.

When I call `provider.refresh()` it seems to be trying to redirect to the Salesforce login page which is clearly not what I want.

**What do I need to update to allow remoting calls to work with the new session information and avoid disrupting the user?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not long after posting this I stumbled across a page in the documentation called [OAuth 2.0 Authentication for JavaScript Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_oauth.htm), that includes this little gem:

> Configuring OAuth for JavaScript remoting from a Visualforce page
>   takes the following form:
>
> ```
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>       Visualforce.remoting.oauthAccessToken = <access_token>;
>       // ...
>   </script>
> ```
>
> Once oauthAccessToken is set, all JavaScript remoting requests use
>   OAuth. The rest of your JavaScript remoting code can remain the same.

This worked a treat, so I could remove the nasty iFrame hack, ignore the providers, and simply do this:

```
    function updateAuthentication(creds)
    {
        Visualforce.remoting.oauthAccessToken = creds.accessToken;
    }
```

Once that has been invoked from the native side of the app all the remoting calls start working as expected!